Jespersen's cycle in the Korean language - Did it ever happen?
Here are my questions:

Did Jespersen's negation cycle ever happen in Korean? I can't seem to find a research done on this topic. If it did happen - when?

Supposing Korean has never gone through the cycle, could it be the Korean syntax that does not allow it to happen?



Jespersen’s cycle is not a given or requirement – it’s just a series of developments that have been observed to occur more frequently than random chance would predict. I don’t know whether it’s ever happened in Korean, but if it hasn’t, we can’t say that there’s anything in Korean syntax that ‘disallows’ it, because it can happen with any kind of syntax: part of its effect is that it changes the syntax of the language, which can happen anywhere.
